# Django - mission impossible - another environment problem

Tags: django

I almost finish my django web aplication, but i never using shell for it. It is hard to checking some things by making changes in code, restarting server and reloading page. But I can't configure django settings environment or something like this.
I do:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings
```

Then:

```
import os

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_project.settings'
```

Then I try:

```
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
'my_project.settings'
```

But when I try:

```
>>> python
>>> import urls
```

I get:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'my_project.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings
```

And when I try:

```
>>> django-admin.py shell
```

I get:

```
Error: Could not import settings 'my_project.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named mysite.settings
```

I am frustrated because of that. The server that I am using have mod_passanger. Does someon know what is the reason of problem? Maybe mod_passanger? Or I am doiung something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do *any* of this. The `manage.py` script does it all for you, which is why you should always use it (instead of django-admin.py) once you're inside a project.

Just do this:

```
./manage.py shell
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

But only if you also have `PYTHONPATH` set properly.

`PYTHONPATH` must include the directory which contains `mysite`.

Also. The `mysite` directory must have an `__init__.py` file to make it into a proper package.

Comment: >>> python
>>> if "/home/my_account/my_project/": print "good"
...
good
And my my_project directory have __init__.py file, but django-admin.py shell still doesn't working

Comment: I have all my files in directory named "my_project"
Sorry I see that I do soemthing wrong above.

Comment: Thanks at all. I know that i am doing something wrong beause of my miss understanding. I will be using ./manage.py shell but i will learn python more. Thanks for patient, good will and knowladge that i can't understand enough in this my learning period.

Answer (score 0):

`./manage.py shell --settings=mysite.settings`

Comment: django-admin.py shell --settings=my_project.settings
gives --->
Error: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named my_project.settings